# Pascal Triangle function not working for row 24 & a few others

Tags: c, factorial, pascals-triangle

I have been given the following problem:

**Given an integer rowIndex, return the rowIndex row of the Pascal's triangle.
Notice that the row index starts from 0.**

Pascal Triangle elements can be predicted with the function: **n! / k!(n-k)!**

My below code works for most entries except a few and I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

For example if I enter **24** all the entries are correct excpet for the second element and second to last element.

I get **[1,23, ...... 23, 1]** when i should get **[1,24, ...... 24, 1]**;

Assuming the math function is correct, 99.99% sure it is, what am I missing here?

```
double factorial(double n);
int* getRow(int rowIndex, int* returnSize){
    
    *returnSize = rowIndex + 1;
    int* ans = malloc(*returnSize * sizeof(int));

    double a = factorial(rowIndex);
    for(int i = 0; i<=rowIndex; i++) {
         ans[i] = a / ( factorial(i) * factorial(rowIndex-i) );
    }
    
    return ans;
}

double factorial(double n) {
    double fact=1;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
            fact *= i;
    }         
    return fact;
}
```

Comment: You are missing the fact that factorial overflows the bit storage available, and possibly that `double` does not sit well with what should be calculations with integers.

Comment: [`24!`](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=24%21) has `20` significant decimal digits, which is more than the usual `double` type can hold.